# Bash Script Watermarking all .jpeg without tumbnails

Tags: linux, bash

problem

```
/a.jpg
/a-150x150.jpg
/a-300x300.jpg
/b.jpg
/b-150x150.jpg
/b-300x300.jpg
```

how do I provide bash script watermarking only on the main image without 150x150 and 300x300 participating in the watermark?

I tried some code but not working. 300x300 remain watermarked

```
file -i *.jpg | grep image | awk -F':' '{ print $1 }' | while read IMAGE
```

I just want

```
/a.jpg
/b.jpg
/c.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` to select exactly the files you want and then feed them to a `while` loop using process substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read filename ; do
    echo "$filename" # your code here
done < <( find . -name '*.jpg' -and -not -regex '.*-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.jpg' )
```

This code uses `-name` to select all `.jpg` images and `-regex` to exclude the  ones with a `-<number>x<number>` pattern (regex has to be written to match the whole filename).

If your code needs to safeguard against exotic filenames with even newlines, you should use the `-print0` switch with `find` and the `-d $'\0'` switch with `read`.

Comment: I think it should be `[0-9]+` (vs *), otherwise `a-x.jpg` qualifies

Comment: and assuming he has 450x450 and the like...I'd probably write it like this:  `find . -regex '.*jpg' -a ! -regex '.*150x150.*' -a ! -regex '.*300x300.*'`

Comment: Some day I'll figure out the `<` in bash...Hasn't clicked yet and I always pipe everything through xargs.  This is nice.

Comment: @zzxyz I agree with your first one, thanks for that. But I would not recommend your second approach. Yes, that would be more targeted, but the script would have to be adapted whenever a new resolution is added.

Comment: Yeah--It's unclear which he'd want, that wasn't intended to be a correction..just a different option.

Comment: @zzxyz Oh, you're welcome to give both corrections and options :) happy bashing.

Comment: You can also use the `-exec` feature of find to run the watermarking program, though it can be fiddly to use.